# unable to send string to same jsp page from controller

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp

i have a jsp page where i have link as follows
dashboars.jsp

```
<li id="">
      <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/student/showAdmissinPage">Admission
    </a>
  </li>
```

when clicked on admission link it will go to controller student

```
                     @GetMapping(value="/showAdmissinPage")
            public String pages() 
            {
                return "studentAdmission";           
            }
```

its returning new page with  studentAdmission  String

i want to receive this studentAdmission String to dashboard.jsp not new page

how can i achieve it with jsp ?

please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add String to model. model.addAtributte(studentAdmissionString, "studentAdmission"); ]Then in jsp use ${studentAdmissionString} to print data.

```
      @GetMapping(value="/showAdmissinPage")
        public String pages() 
        {
            String s = "studentAdmission";
            model.addAtributte("studentAdmissionString", s);
            return "dashboard";           
        }
```

then in dashboard use `${studentAdmissionString}` to print value :)

Answer (score 0):

one of my friend ankit helped with this as follows

modelMap.addAttribute("demo","studentadmission"); 
and 
return "dashboard"; 
don't return studentadmission .